# Wireless connection of camera feed without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, ip, wireless-access-point, camera

I am trying to share the live feed of camera connected on my laptop to another laptop wirelessly without internet over 1km range.

Like I want to see the live feed of camera attached to my laptop over another laptop simultaneously.

I have studied and seen many products but the issue either comes with the distance or the transmission rate or some uses WiFi.

Comment: Consumer wifi over 1 Km ?  No chance. You need commercial gear for this.

Comment: Measure the cost of a 1 Km commercial wireless solution (expensive ) against the cost of low bandwidth Internet at the site and a small, top quality always on computer. Manage the computer (and so the camera) over the internet.